# apache commons VFS : how to resolve file having % character in file name?

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

How to run apache common VFS resolovefile on my file with % character in the name  ?

```
org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Invalid URI escape sequence "%FILENAME"
```

Regards,

G Samrat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percent is an escape character in URIs so it must itself be escaped as `%25`.